# lambda function in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, closures

im kinda new to this whole concept of lambda functions and closure,
so i started to write this simple program ,
but im getting errors on those lines, and i dont know how to fix it

and the output should be:
on line 31: 1 2 5 3

on line 32: 2 3 6 4

on line 45: 5 4 3

on line 49:3 0 1

on line 53:2 2 2

on line 57:3 0 1

```
function <int(int)> F[n], G[n];

for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    F[i] = [&F, &i](int x){ return (x < i) ? x : F[i](x - i); };
    G[i] = [&G, i](int x){ return (x < i) ? x : G[i](x - i); };
}
```

and im getting those errors:

Error   1   error C2065: 'function' : undeclared identifier d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    36  1   tester

Error   2   error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ')' d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    36  1   tester

Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : ')' d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    36  1   tester

Error   4   error C2065: 'F' : undeclared identifier    d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    40  1   tester

Error   5   error C3481: 'F': lambda capture variable not found d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    40  1   tester

Error   6   error C2065: 'G' : undeclared identifier    d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    41  1   tester

Error   7   error C3481: 'G': lambda capture variable not found d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    41  1   tester

Error   8   error C2065: 'F' : undeclared identifier    d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    45  1   tester

Error   9   error C2065: 'G' : undeclared identifier    d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    49  1   tester

Error   10  error C2065: 'F' : undeclared identifier    d:\c++ 
projects\tester\tester\source.cpp   53  1   tester

Error   11  error C2065: 'G' : undeclared identifier    d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    57  1   tester

Error   12  error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type   d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    40  1   tester

Error   13  error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type   d:\c++ projects\tester\tester\source.cpp    41  1   tester

this is my whole program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Opp
{
  int n;

public:

Opp() : n(0){}
Opp(int x) : n(x){}
Opp(const Opp& Q) : n(Q.n + 1){};

Opp operator ()(int x){ return Opp(x + 2); }

friend void Print(Opp *A, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << A[i].n << "\t";
    cout << endl;
 };
};

  int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

Opp A = Opp(1), B(2), C = A(3), D(B), P[4];

P[0] = A; P[1] = B; P[2] = C; P[3] = D;

Opp Q[] = { A, B, C, D };

Print(P, 4);
Print(Q, 4);

const int n = 14;
int i;
function <int(int)> F[n], G[n];

for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    F[i] = [&F, &i](int x){ return (x < i) ? x : F[i](x - i); };
    G[i] = [&G, i](int x){ return (x < i) ? x : G[i](x - i); };
}

for (i = 10; i < n - 1; i++)
    cout << F[n - i](15) << "\t";
cout << endl;

for (i = 10; i < n - 1; i++)
    cout << G[n - i](15) << "\t";
cout << endl;

for (int i = 10; i < n - 1; i++)
    cout << F[n - i](15) << "\t";
cout << endl;

for (int i = 10; i < n - 1; i++)
    cout << G[n - i](15) << "\t";
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you *do* know what errors you get? And you want to keep that information for yourself, because you do not believe it is useful to anyone else?

Comment: Please put error messages verbatim in your question.

Comment: And also examples of your input and what it was supposed to output. See [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help].

Comment: i edited the question with the output and the errors im getting

Comment: The compiler won't reject it, but capturing i by reference `[&F, &i]` will capture a reference to the loop variable i. Therefore all your lambda's capture the same reference, and they are all invalid after the loop ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use function, you must include functional.
add follow line after `#include  <iostream>`

```
#include <functional>
```